# QueryDsl/MapPath help needed

Tags: spring, jpa, querydsl

Updating my question to be more specific.

My entity is a `Map<String, String>`

I build generic queries using reflection. For all other types, I can build a path (`PathBuilder`) and then evaluate appropriately (`equals`, `contains`, `startswith`, etc).
For string types I can then get the `StringExpression` by invoking `path.getString(fieldName)`. I can then use the `startsWith`, `endsWith`, etc methods to evaluate.

I don't see how to handle this with a `Map`.
I have a `MapPath`...is there way to resolve this to a `StringExpression` so that I can evaluate if the value `startsWith` or `endsWith` a particular value.
Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve a Map path only via a join to a String path

```
query.join(entity.mapPath, stringPath)
```

Comment: Do you know how do I do the same for selecting?